# Javascript how to create a date with a non-english string

Tags: javascript

```
var date = new Date ("Mai 15, 2018 10:41:48");
```

The string is in German.
I am receiving error "Invalid Date" as expected because JS wants me to put in english.

I do not want to use `toLocaleString()` as I am trying to initialize the date from a different language.

Comment: what is name of language/

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz edited the post . "Its German"

Comment: Use moment.js..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `moment.js`  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

```js
let localLocale = moment();

localLocale.locale('de'); // set this instance to use German
let date = localLocale.date("Mai 15, 2018 10:41:48").toDate();
console.log(date);

// if you don't want to add this dependency, you can do something like this 


let str = 'Mai 15, 2018 10:41:48';
const months = {
  Januar: 'January',
  Februar: 'February',
  'März': 'Macrh',
  Marz: 'March',
  April: 'April',
  Mai: 'May',
  Juni: 'June',
  Juli: 'July',
  August: 'August',
  September: 'September',
  Oktober: 'October',
  November: 'November',
  Dezember: 'December'
};

let month = str.split(' ')[0];
console.log(new Date(str.replace(month, months[month])));

// I am leaving timezone handling to you. Put some effort
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot import any new jars without a long process of approvals.

Comment: Hmm this approach adds  a lot of hardcoding ..I guess since I am dealing with internationalization I would have to do the same for almost all the languages . I wanted to avoid this ..But thanks for your response. I'll accept your answer.